# What are the differences between Append and load data in ArcGIS?

Tags: esri-geodatabase, arcgis-desktop

I confused about differences between Append tool in Arctoolbox and Load data in Geodatabase.
I think both of them are the same in the result feature class.Both of them use a default output feature class and compare the target feature geometry and schema with another feature but there are differences in some aspects such as performance that I don't know .Another question is that where can i use Append instead of Load data ?

Thanks for advance

Comment: Object Loader http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/about-loading-data-into-existing-feature-classes-a.htm is very misleading because it says you can use it for Tables. This NOT true if the Table is held in a Relationship class. This should be noted!! The append tool also does not allow tables to have the same name when appending from 1 geodatabase to another. Ridiculous!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/114454)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/114454)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Object Loader` and `Simple Data Loader` allow you to load data into empty feature classes or feature classes that already contain data.

The Simple Data Loader also allows you to load into stand-alone tables.

While the Object Loader and Simple Data Loader are similar loading wizards, the Object Loader provides the following functionality that the Simple Data Loader does not have:

> Because the Object Loader loads data during an edit session in ArcMap, once you've finished loading, you can undo the changes if
>   needed.
>       If the feature coordinates you're loading are not precisely located, you can choose to honor the current snapping environment,
>   snapping coordinates as they load.
>       If you're loading into a feature class that has validation rules, such as attribute domain or geometric network connectivity rules, you
>   can validate the features added and create a selection of the loaded
>   features that are in violation of these rules.
>       With the Object Loader, you can load into feature classes in a geometric network, feature classes in a relationship with messaging,
>   or **feature classes that have feature-linked annotation.** You cannot
>   load into these types of feature classes with the Simple Data Loader.

**Appending Geoodatabases**

Append geoprocessing tool. This is useful if loading data is going to be used as part of a batch process, but generally the above methods are better for all other occasions

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003n0000003r000000

Comment: Object Loader and Simple Data Loader Can not load into a table that is not simple (e.g. has relationship). Append tool can help in this case too.